# Glassfish server 4 does not reflect change in List.xhtml file

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, glassfish

I'm using NetBeans 7.4 with GlassFish Server 4.
I have this CRUD application using JavaServer Faces and Hibernate.
I was referencing an object
 which got the error

> The class 'entities.InvhistoryController' does not have the property
>   'triggerAsc'

So I changed it to remove that object reference

I've used 'clean and build' the app and restarted glassfish many times but still get the same error above.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Clean & Build should fix this issue, if it doesn't you might have another reference to the specific property.

To make sure, run a full-text search over your project for the property in the error message.

As a last resort you might restart NetBeans, but normally Clean & Build should be sufficient.

Comment: I think I have a serious problem with NetBeans. Now when I try to run the project I get Incrementally deploying FOFVehicles
Completed incremental distribution of FOFVehicles
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/FOFVehicles
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds) But it doesn't show up in the browser?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't automatically open the browser window? Then just manually navigate to this URL. If it opens automatically and nothing is shown, check the source code in the browser to see if your XHTML gets parsed.

Comment: Yes it doesn't open the browser window.When I manually navigate using the URL it comes up and when I log in the other tables all show up but the one with the problem still shows that error.And yes I did a full-text search for the offending property and it does not exist anywhere in the code!

Comment: Sounds something is seriously wrong somewhere. Maybe you should upgrade to NetBeans 8.0.2 (althought this has to work with NetBeans 7.4). It is always recommended to use the current stable version of any piece of software.

Comment: I was thinking of that. Do you know if it uses GlassFish 4 ?

Comment: You can use it with Glassfish 3 or 4. Just add your existing server instance via the `Services` tab in NetBeans.

Comment: Thank you for your help unwichtich.Good to know I'm not alone.

Comment: Well I downloaded NetBeans 8.0.2 and still can't get rid of that persistent property error.I'm at my wits end it's like the Glassfish server is stuck and does not republish changes to my files in Netbeans.I'm considering System Restore but that probably won't help either.Can anyone suggest somethin that might help?

Comment: You can try it on a new instance of Glassfish. Just download the ZIP package, extract it somewhere and add the new server instance in NetBeans in the Services tab. Then configure your project to run on the new instance.

Comment: I just did that and still the error persists.Also tried deleting browser's cache.I downloaded a fresh version of Glassfish and added it to the services tab of NetBeans.Redeployed the project to the new server and Still get the error.I could scream now!

Comment: That really sounds like an error in the matrix :) Maybe you can put your code on GitHub or something else so that people can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
The code did contain a commented-out reference to the so-called invalid property.
Apparently the browser parsed the comment and threw an error.I removed the line completely and the error went away.Then I put the thing back to a non-commented version and it works like a charm.I'm still not sure why the commented-out code was being parsed, but I'm happy that my problem was resolved.
Thank You for all your help and patience.
-Reg